# How to move the full tree of orgchart js balkan using javascript?

Tags: javascript, orgchart

I would like to move the tree of Balkan orgchart js using javascript.

(https://balkan.app/OrgChartJS/Docs/GettingStarted)

Ideally with button right , left , top , bottom for each moves.
The tree can move with hold and move of the mouse, but I can not find ways to move it using javascript command only.

Any help would be welcome

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use the new moveStart and moveEnd methods from the latest version

Here is a [Code demo](https://code.balkan.app/org-chart-js/movestart-and-moveend-methods#JS)

Clear your browser cache and test the Code above

Disclaimer: I'm a developer at BALKAN App

Comment: Thanks @plamen-peshev , can this be combined with the coordinates of the chart?. i.e. I would like to move 2 graph simultaneously so that I should not use the mouse at all.

Comment: yes, you can achieve that, just use the moveStart and moveEnd methods for both chart

Comment: is there a way for the move to be faster? I see a duration attribute on the moveStart, do you have an example on how to use this parameter? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The way to make it work was done with using a timer with setTimeout

```
 moveGraphUp() {
    console.log("Moving up");
   
    this.chart.moveStart({
            up: true 
        });
    setTimeout(() => {  console.log("ending move"); this.chart.moveEnd(); }, 500); 
    
    console.log("Moved up");
}
```

Note: We have 2 screens open and the idea is to triggered it on both side so that the graph is mirrored similarly on both side. And we don't want to use mouse over as the mirroring wouldn't be synchronised well.

Ideally We need a moveStart with a number of steps to move. (Click only one click => run with javascript which would be update simultaneously on my 2 screens ) but the timer is working too.